# MySQL query is very slow when adding JOIN into WHERE

Tags: mysql

The following query runs quickly except when I add in the 'areacode.hours = 2'. Instead of taking a second it now takes close to a minute.

```
SELECT lead.id, first, last, lead.phone, valid_phone, mobile_phone 
FROM lead 
LEFT JOIN dnt ON dnt.phone = lead.phone
LEFT JOIN areacode ON areacode.code = LEFT(lead.phone, 3)
LEFT JOIN campaign ON campaign.id = lead.campaign_id
WHERE dnt.id IS NULL 
AND campaign.lft BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 
AND lead.datetime BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-06-01 23:59:59' 
AND areacode.hours = 2
GROUP BY lead.phone
ORDER BY lead.phone DESC
LIMIT 1,1000
```

Results of EXPLAIN

```
1   SIMPLE  lead    index   campaign_id,datetime    phone   13  NULL    181181  Using where
1   SIMPLE  campaign    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   data3_db.lead.campaign_id   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  areacode    ref code,hours  code    11  func    1   Using index condition; Using where
1   SIMPLE  dnt ref phone   phone   12  data3_db.lead.phone 1   Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

Comment: 1. Use EXPLAIN to check index usage / 2. add an index on areacode.hours

Comment: You should run `EXPLAIN` on your query.  Off the top of my head, adding an index to `areacode.hours` could help here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just curious here, why would you add an index to `areacode.hours` but not the other fields? I am new to indexing.

Comment: @DavidLee I would add indices to the other columns most likely.  It is 1am here and I was too lazy to type this :-)

Comment: Move the limit to the join instead of the where clause.  in fact, all limits for tables on the right side of a left join should be on the join or you negate the left join making it act like an inner join.

Comment: Were you getting the desired results before the  new limit?  seems to me limits on campaign and areacode in the where clause would eliminate records from LEAD when no related record is found in areacode or campaign.  Is this desired? If so then why use left joins, they should be inner joins.

Comment: EXPLAIN has been added

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen For sure, thanks for the info.

Comment: Group by w/o aggregate in mySQL uses group by extension if older version; or if enabled.  Is the reduction of data the right data being removed?

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause limits are being executed after the joins complete.  This will result in your left joins acting like INNER joins.  I would recommend moving the limits for those tables on the right side of a left join to the joins themselves; so the limits are applied before the join occurs. (or as part of it)

Exception would be if you're checking for Null on a field; That could remain in the where clause.  but you have no way to distinguish between dnt.ids which are are  null in the table, and those which are null as part of the left join if you put it in the where clause.  However, given this is an "ID" field I'll assume it can't be null and leaving it in the where makes sense.

At times the compiler may attempt to apply the filter after the join when you have thousands of records * 4 tables you record growth could be large; by moving the limits to occur before/on join, the engine can reduce the temporary datset it has to build before it filters out the records. On Inner joins this doesn't matter but on outer joins it can not only effect performance; but desired results.

```
SELECT lead.id, first, last, lead.phone, valid_phone, mobile_phone 
FROM lead 
LEFT JOIN dnt 
  ON dnt.phone = lead.phone
LEFT JOIN areacode 
  ON areacode.code = LEFT(lead.phone, 3)
 AND areacode.hours = 2
LEFT JOIN campaign 
  ON campaign.id = lead.campaign_id
 AND campaign.lft BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 
WHERE lead.datetime BETWEEN '2017-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-06-01 23:59:59' 
  AND dnt.id IS NULL 
GROUP BY lead.phone
ORDER BY lead.phone DESC
LIMIT 1,1000
```

If that still doesn't produce the desired results and time, then i'd look at desired indexes.

Comment: I believe they would need to be inner joins in my case. I need leads that belong to campaigns that have a lft between 0 and 1000. If I do it with a left join and include it in the join then it would also give me leads outside of those campaigns as well. Correct?

Comment: It appears that the GROUP BY is causing most of the delay. It takes a split second to run without grouping it. However, I don't want to pull the same number more than once.

Comment: remove group by and add a distinct.  You're not using aggregates and an article I just recently read said in mySQL Distinct can be faster.  though evaluation of execution plan/indexes would be the only way to know.  Though the article says w/ proper indexes, the group by should be better performance.  I was worried that your desired results were flawed as well thus the question on left joins and where clause.

Comment: DISTINCT runs quick but would not work as it would give me duplicate phone numbers. Unless there is some way around that? The reason for GROUP by phone is so that we don't get the same phone multiple times. Distinct could give me the same phone number with different names.

Comment: Ok.. so what other information should be listed for each phone number? perhaps we just needed to max or min the other data? You're taking advantage of mySQL's group by extensions; which selects a value for ID, first, last, valid_phone and mobile_phone for you but that value could be inconsistent each run, Think of this: if I have IDs 1,2 associated to the same lead.phone... which one would you want? and do you want the relevant data associated to the ID selected?

Comment: FORCE INDEX (datetime) seems to fix the issue. I noticed after applying the limit the lead table was indexed by the phone value and not the datetime like normal. Not sure if this is the correct approach but it appears to work.

Comment: I would be worried that the data comming back isn't really what you need.  Focus in on a single phone number with multiple ID's and ask yourself what you should get back for that record w/ multiple IDs...

Comment: For the other fields I could just do MAX for each one. I need the lead.id for recording a message that goes out. First/Last for including in the message, and I need to make sure the number was valid and mobile. I will test that out as well.